# Can't use conditions on symbols. DataMapper with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm getting troubles when trying to use conditions on symbols in DataMapper:

```
 clusters = Cluster.all(:latitude.not => nil)
```

This code throws an error:

```
ArgumentError - condition #<Origin::Key:0x50d05a0 @name=:latitude, @strategy=:__override__, @operator="$not", @expanded=nil, @block=
nil> of an unsupported object Origin::Key:
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/query.rb:888:in `block in assert_valid_conditions'
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/query.rb:853:in `each'
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/query.rb:853:in `assert_valid_conditions'
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/query.rb:776:in `block in assert_valid_options'
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/query.rb:766:in `each'
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/query.rb:766:in `assert_valid_options'
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/query.rb:363:in `update'
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/query.rb:386:in `merge'
        C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/model.rb:767:in `scoped_query'
```

Cluster model class:

```
class Cluster
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,               Serial
  property :city_id,          Integer
  property :name,             String
  property :latitude,         Float
  property :longitude,        Float      
end
```

Core gem versions I'm using: `sinatra` - 1.4.6, `data_mapper` - 1.2.0.

What can be wrong with this code? Can't resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
clusters = Cluster.all - Cluster.all(:latitude => nil)
```

[Reference](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html) (Combining Queries 13)

Comment: Yep, it works. Is this line executes 2 queries? Don't think that it is quite elegant solution. But still, it works, thank you.

Comment: @Antrille yea,unfortunately it executes 2 queries.. That's strange `.not` does not work for you, but that's the only thing I came up as a workaround